# undefined gets outputted instead of object properties

Tags: javascript

Why the `undefined` gets outputted instead of the object properties.

Created a function, defined setters for the parameters and function to output the string consisting of the parameters.

Below is the snippet for the app.js file.

```js
// app.js

function Fruit(theColor, sweetness, theName, theOrigin) {
 
 //properties
 this.theColor  = theColor;
 this.sweetness  = sweetness;
 this.theName  = theName;
 this.theOrigin  = theOrigin;
 
 //functions
 this.showName = function () {
  console.log("This is a " + this.theName);
 };

 this.showLand = function () {
  this.theOrigin.forEach(function (arg) {
   console.log("Grown in: " + arg);
  });
 };
}

var mango = new Fruit("Yellow", 9, "Mango", ["India", "Central America"]);

console.log(mango.showName() + " " + mango.showLand());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
console.log(mango.showName() + " " + mango.showLand());
```

calls those functions, then outputs their return values with a space between them. Neither `showNames` nor `showLand` returns anything, and so calling them gives you the result `undefined`.

If you just want to *call* those, just call them, without using `console.log` to output their result. E.g., replace:

```
console.log(mango.showName() + " " + mango.showLand());
```

with

```
mango.showName();
mango.showLand();
```

If you want them to *return*, rather than display, their result, edit them to do so. You'll have to decide how you want `showLand` to separate lines (e.g., with a `\n`, or by returning an array, etc.).

For instance, this `showName` will return a string, and `showLand` will return an array:

```
//functions
this.showName = function () {
    return "This is a " + this.theName;
};

this.showLand = function () {
    return this.theOrigin.map(function (arg) {
        return "Grown in: " + arg;
    });
};
```

which you could then call like this:

```
console.log(mango.showName() + ". " + mango.showLand().join(", "));
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function Fruit(theColor, sweetness, theName, theOrigin) {

    //properties
    this.theColor   = theColor;
    this.sweetness  = sweetness;
    this.theName    = theName;
    this.theOrigin  = theOrigin;

    //functions
    this.showName = function () {
        return "This is a " + this.theName;
    };

    this.showLand = function () {
        return this.theOrigin.map(function (arg) {
            return "Grown in: " + arg;
        });
    };
}

var mango = new Fruit("Yellow", 9, "Mango", ["India", "Central America"]);

console.log(mango.showName() + ". " + mango.showLand().join(", "));
```

Comment: that means inorder not to display undefined i need to add return statement

Comment: @d_CoDE44: No, that's not what it means. It means you don't want to use `console.log` to call them at all. **Or** you want to remove `console.log` from them, and instead have them return what you want to display.